# Uniqueness validation returning false non-uniqueness

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord

Adding states to an empty database, where State `validates :name, uniqueness: true`.

Again, the DB is empty!

```rb
State.create(name:"Alabama")                                                                                                  
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  State Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "states" WHERE "states"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "Alabama"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
=> #<State:0x00007ffb711c3c60 id: nil, name: "Alabama", region_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
State.all                                                                                                                     
  State Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "states".* FROM "states"
=> []
```

Why does it say this state exists when NO states exist???

When I get rid of the uniqueness validation, it's still acting funny:

```rb
State.all                                                                                                                      
  State Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "states".* FROM "states"
=> []
```

Comment: Try `State.create!(name:"Alabama")` and see what it throws

Comment: Turns out I had a `belongs_to` relationship that needed to be set to `optional: true`.